# What is the purpose of the Socket class within the pthreads extension for PHP

Tags: php, sockets, php-pthread

The pthreads extension for PHP has an undocumented socket class appropriately named 'Socket'. The extension's examples folder has at least one [example](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/NonBlockingSocketServer.php) that uses the Socket class, but other than that (and surfing the [extension's C code](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/src/socket.c)) one wouldn't even know it exists.

I have three questions:

- Given PHP's existing and mature socket functions, what is the purpose of this new Socket class?
- Assuming that it's an attempt to make at least some socket resources / functions safer for use between threads, what is it's limitations?
- The class is not just a simple wrapper of existing socket functions but an exhaustive socket implementation in it's own right. What is the over all development status of the class?

Comment: Interesting question. I didn't know there was a socket implementation in pthreads. Although I would imagine you would have a better chance getting an answer on pthreads' github repo.

Comment: They direct general questions to stack overflow but I will likely post there as well